# Storing strings with ampersand "&" in SharedPreferences Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I tried storing a `String` with an "&" in it and noticed that when I try to grab the `String` it isn't the same as before. It basically gets cut off.

The original `String` might look like `something=value&something2=value2` and the resulting string might look like `something=value`.

I couldn't find any documentation about what kinds of characters are allowed to be stored, but does anyone know if "&" has some kind of restriction in `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: I can type `foo=bar&goo=baz` into an `EditTextPreference` and retrieve it just fine.

Comment: As CommonsWare suggests, it depends on how you are saving data to `SharedPreferences`. `SharedPreferences` are stored in XML files and `&` is a special character as are `>` and `<`. Depending on how you are saving your values, you may need to 'escape' ampersand as `&amp;`. The same goes for `>` and `<` which are `&gt;` and `&lt;` respectively.

Comment: Also...please post some code to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Right now I used `URLEncode.encode` and that seems to solve it, but I still want to know if there is another way or if it's just `SharedPreferences` that doesn't accept `&`.

Comment: Edit your original question. Don't add an answer just to provide extra information to the question.